# Python 3: unable to understand the 2nd iteration

Tags: python-3.x

Using the below mentioned python code, I am reading the number entered by the user and printing the series.

```
n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
for j in range(1,n+1):
    a=[]
    for i in range(1,j+1):
        print(i,sep=" ",end=" ")
        if(i<j):
            print("+",sep=" ",end=" ")
        a.append(i)
    print("=",sum(a))
```

When I run this code, I am seeing the below mentioned output.

```
RESTART: C:\SKANAKAV\at&t\Python\Aricent_Python\python_scripts\Read a Number 
n And Print the Series_contdddd\test_exercise.py 
Enter a number: 2
1 = 1
1 + 2 = 3
```

User has entered the number 2 which is 'n'. For the 1st 'for' loop -> j is (1,3) where j has the value 1 now. For the 2nd 'for' loop -> i is (1,2). In the next line it prints '1' and then for the 'if' condition (i 1<1) which is 'false' and hence comes out of the loop and appends i(1) to 'a'.now the final output is printed as 1 = 1.

I am able to understand till this which means the 1st iteration. now here is where I am not able to understand the program flow. it goes back to the 1st for loop where 'j' becomes 2 now.
a is again an empty list.
now for the 2nd 'for' loop -> (1,3) -> 'i' is again 1 now.
Now we print 1 and then get into the 'if' condition (i (1<2) which is 'true' and hence gets into the loop and prints '+'.

Now again 'a' becomes 1 as 'i' is 1.
going by this, it should print -> 1 + = 1.
But it prints 1 + 2 = 3.
Can someone please help me understand this program flow?

Comment: In your last paragraph, For the second loop `i` will be 2, since it was 1 the previous time through the loop.  Why do you think it will be 1?

Answer (score -1):

Ok let's go over the second loop as you did with the first one. I will be listing the variables values.

```
j = 2
a = []
i = 1
print i (1)
1 < 2 = true
print '+' (1 +)
a = [1]
print i (1 + 2)
2 < 2 = false
a = [1, 2]
print =, sum(a) (1 + 2 = 3)
```

your range in the second loop goes from 1 to j + 1 (3 now)

Comment: Thanks for your response Julio. Appreciate it. Now I am able to understand the 2nd loop.